# Printing a dictionary value in Swift

Tags: dictionary, printing, swift

I'm trying to get my dictionary in Swift to print out.
If my dictionary is

```
var airports = ["ALB":"Albany International", "ORD": "O'Hare"]
```

and I print it out by saying

```
airports["ALB"]
```

It returns

```
{Some "Albany International"}
```

I've noticed that this also happens whenever I have an optional variable.

Is there some way to keep it from including that some?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the key is there, you can print the value with an exclamation point:

```
var airports = ["ALB":"Albany International", "ORD": "O'Hare"]
println(airports["ALB"])  // Prints Optional("Albany International")
println(airports["ALB"]!) // Prints Albany International
```

If you are not sure that the key is there, and you would like to avoid an error, you can do this:

```
if let alb = airports["ALB"] {
    print(alb)
}
```

Function `print` will be called only when `"ALB"` key is present in the dictionary, in which case `alb` would be assigned a non-optional `String`.

Comment: Does the exclamation point have any particular meaning? Is there a name for that feature of the language?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Exclamation point after an expression is an operator that performs a forced [unwrapping](https://learnappmaking.com/swift-optionals-how-to/) of an optional value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp_array: Dictionary = [
    1:"John",
    2:"Ann",
    3:"Tom",
    4:"Juan",
    5:"Sarah"
]
let value = temp_array[3]!;
print(value)
```